# Ploting a box plot with a density plot side by side in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to compare the data between to labeled groups, using box plots and density plots. I made a function for that, to make it easier ust entering the data I need and what feature I would like to use, and what is the label of the two groups (`y` would be a binary feature):

```
density_and_boxplot = function(data = data, metadata = metadata, cell.type = 'cell.type', y = c()) {

  combination = merge(data, metadata, by=0, all=TRUE) %>% na.omit()
  p1 = ggplot(data = combination, aes(x= cell.type, fill=as.factor(y))) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + title(paste('Box plot of',cell.type))
  p2 = ggplot(data = combination, aes(x= cell.type, fill=as.factor(y))) + geom_density(alpha=.5) + title(paste('Distribtuion of',cell.type))
 
  return(cowplot::plot_grid(p1,p2))
}
```

Calling the function:

```
density_and_boxplot(data = scores, metadata = mydata, cell.type = 'B-cells', y = 'PD')
```

I get empty plots, why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput()`?

Comment: Without being able to see your data, it looks like you're plotting a single point in each, by passing `x = 'B-cells'`.  Try replacing `x = cell.type` with `x = .data[[cell.type]].

Comment: Great, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing your `cell.type` variable to the line `x = cell.type` in the `aes()` calls leads to a plot with `aes(x = "B-cells")` NOT `aes(x = B-cells)` as you might hope - i.e. it passes the string instead of selecting the existing variable in your dataset.

Instead, use: `x = .data[[cell.type]]`